# has the site became less welcoming...?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I raised a [question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/197211/should-i-put-my-two-methods-right-under-the-main) earlier.

Here is a screenshot of it:

[image: question]

and the Comments

[image: Close Reason and Comments]

I'd be honest, it is not the best question I've asked so far.

But to have a minus 4 for that question?

That's weird for a site who is doing code review and should be helping ppl improving their coding knowledge.

Has the site become a Stack Overflow bis repetita in the aspect that we should avoid like the exclusiveness of the people who knows vs the people who are learning...?

Only asking.

Comment: @AndyK I personally don't understand in what way you feel this was unwelcoming... It was closed due to lack of concrete context, I was not one of the voters but I tend to agree, it looks like the code is placeholder to substantiate your very broad question.

Comment: Were there any comments below the question explaining the downvotes?

Comment: @Mast very brief like I was hiding something was one of the comments. You were one of the first to welcome me here. And yet, now, my question has been closed like it was meaningless. Please close the meta if you feel this is the way to treat my question on meta.

Comment: I wanted to delete my question but actually, I'm going to keep it, with the negative votes. It is not a matter of vote, it is matter that I feel my question was treated as off topic, without trying to understand any of it. Fair enough, it is not the best question, fair enough, I'm a low rep user on that site, but at least, comments could have been constructive. And that bugs me, reminding of the days when questions were closed on SO because some guys have decided that someone's python level was poor or that another one did not do enough homework... Not sure what to think of the whole thing...

Comment: Code quality is not a problem here. If your code is awful, we just have more to teach. But if the question isn't fit for the site, it isn't fit for the site. We simply can't allow too much deviation from the rules or we'll be swamped with questions we can't handle. There's a plethora of reasons not to allow anything that looks even remotely like it needs help.

Comment: Yes, mistakes will be made. But honestly, this is a very constructive community and I have my doubts about your attitude. I simply don't see the justification for the amount of negativity from your side. Please, if anything went wrong (I'll leave it to those involved and/or moderators to figure out whether it did), keep an open mind about it. We can all be constructive in this.

Comment: @Mast Shutting my question, I'm ok as long as I have a more detailed explanations. Your explanation is very clear and I thank you for that. 

Now you may see me I'm negative because I'm speaking up and I feel the situation is not fair, you are free to see it that way and I won't disagree with you nor disagree.

I can say much more but I will keep it as it is for the night.  

Thank you again.

Comment: @AndyK if we can talk in my chat room (located in my profile) I think I can help clear a few other comments up.

Comment: @FreezePhoenix No offense, but I don't think you're the best person to clear things up. You have 317 reputation and not much previous meta activity on CR. Additionally, the room you are linking to is not even a CR room - it's an AI room. Please keep the discussions about CR in rooms belonging to Code Review.

Comment: @AndyK Do you have any suggestions for how the comments on your original post could be more constructive?

Comment: @SimonForsberg probably being a bit more verbose, taking a bit of time to comment and to have step on the other one shoes. Take yourself in my shoes and imagine also that I'm a very much of a noob. If you got 4 downvotes in a row with minimal explanation, how would you feel? If the aim is the treat the question as business as usual and close it as quickly behind, fair enough, this may be the right way, although from my personal experiences, this is a real turn-off.

If you want people to come back and hopefully improve, what would you do yourself...?

Comment: I've changed my initial question, please have a look. It should be clearer.

Comment: @AndyK I understand, and I totally agree. I do believe it's very important to write good comments, and it is possible to write a comment that is both strict, welcoming, and clear.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, the site has not become less welcoming.  Code Review users are not out to harm anyone.  Rather, we're looking out for the quality of questions on the site.  The comments you received were trying to help you improve the question.

You've posted good questions before.  This one wasn't as good.  I felt that the question was not answerable in its original form, so I downvoted it, and stated my reason in a comment:

> This is an awkward library. Why do these two pieces of functionality belong together in the same program or library? Also, the `conn_wr()` function looks like a hypothetical example or placeholder for some other functionality. I feel like you're hiding something from us in this question, and it's hard to advise you properly.

I would be glad to undo my downvote (and encourage others to do so) if you improved the question by providing the necessary context for a review.

This is in addition to @SamOnela's observation that Code Review titles should simply state the task accomplished by the code, as per the [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) guidelines.

Comment: Hi @200_success, thank you for your clarifying comment. Now it makes sense. Let me reframe my question.